# Error de conexion a base de datos con Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, passport

Estoy instalando una API con Laravel Passport utilizando bases de datos POSTGRESQL.
Al momento de instalar Laravel y la autenticación básica, funciona ok al punto de registrar usuarios y hacer login perfectamente. (toma la base de datos ok) Pero al momento de seguir los pasos para instalar Passport y correr el comando php artisan migrate, Passport no reconoce que estoy usando POSTGRESQL y busca la conexión a MYSQL, que es inexistente.

probe si es un tema de cache corriendo:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

y no funciona. Agradeceré ayuda!

Tengo en config/databases:

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),  donde tengo el postgresql

y en el .env tengo deshabilitado MYSQL:

```
#DB_CONNECTION=mysql
#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
#DB_PORT=3306
#DB_DATABASE=laravel
#DB_USERNAME=root
#DB_PASSWORD=
```

El error que tira por consola es:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: 
create table `oauth_auth_codes` (`id` varchar(100) not null, `user_id` bigint unsigned not 
null, `client_id` bigint unsigned not null, `scopes` text null, `revoked` tinyint(1) not 
null, `expires_at` datetime null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 
'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the 
error
668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
670|         catch (Exception $e) {
671|             throw new QueryException(
672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
673|             );
674|         }
675|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finalmente encontré la solución en un foro de Laravel Passport, parece que en las últimas versiones la conexión a la db se configura directamente en passport (no se porque no toma la de .env o config/databases), "publicando" (exportando) del vendor a la app el archivo de conexión que incluye el Passport Storage Driver, para poder modificarlo y declarar la conexión exclusivamente para Passport.
Demás esta decir que hay en Laravel 3 lugares diferentes para declarar una conexión a la base de datos, tema para charlar directamente con Otwell.

En fin, esto se hace con el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

que agrega un file en la carpeta config llamado passport.php, y donde encontramos, listo para configurar:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Passport Storage Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This configuration options determines the storage driver that will
| be used to store Passport's data. In addition, you may set any
| custom options as needed by the particular driver you choose.
|
*/

'storage' => [
    'database' => [
        'connection' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    ],
],
```